# How to make an entire script wait for response from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, promise, fetch

I'm getting some data from `Firebase` and exporting this data to another script as an object, but since `script-2.js` is executed before the response in the `script-1.js` gets returned, I'm not able to get the data in time. I'm fairly new with both Firebase and promises and I'm having a hard time with them right now.

My project is something like this:

SCRIPT 1 (fetching data and storing it into `fetchedData`):

```
let fetchedData= {}

const db = firebase.firestore()

const getTechs = () => {
    return db.collection('techs').get()
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async e => {
    const querySnapshot = await getTechs()

    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const key = Object.keys(doc.data())
        const value = Object.values(doc.data())
        fetchedData[key] = value
    })
    
})

export default fetchedData
```

SCRIPT 2 (Importing `fetchedData` from `script-1.js`

```
import fetchedData from './script-1.js'

console.log(fetchedData) // => here I have an empty object, since it's not populated yet.

//...do something with the data
```

If I was fetching the data and using it in the same script I could make this work, but I'm going to use `fetchedData` on multiple other scripts, so it would be nice not to have to fetch it on all of them.

How could I solve this?

P.S. I already tried with a hard coded object in `script-1.js` and worked fine, the problem really is what I described.

Comment: `export` and `import` a Promise that gets resolved at the end of your event listener. In your second script, `await` that Promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export a Promise which would (eventually) resolve to your fetched data:

```js
/* script 1 */

let resolve;
const promise = new Promise(r => resolve = r);

// eventually
resolve(data);

export default promise;

/* script 2 */
import fetchedDataPromise from './script-1.js';

// whenever you need it
const fetchedData = await fetchedDataPromise;
```

Alternatively, you could try to delay the execution of the 2nd script. Depending on how/when that gets executed, that might be possible.